# How to set zorder across axis in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, z-order

I want to make a graph that contains bars, the value of the bars noted above them and a line on the secondary axis, but I can't configure the order of the elements the way I want where the bars would be the furthest element, followed by the line and then the texts, but so far I can only change the position of an entire axis and either the line goes over the text or is behind the bars.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

years = [2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2023]
values1 = [1350, 1360, 1420, 1480, 1650]
values2 = [57, 62, 60.5, 59.7, 62.3]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6.2, 7.36), dpi = 150)
bars = ax.bar(years, values1)

heights = []
for bar in bars:
    bar.set_zorder(2)
    height = bar.get_height()
    heights.append(height)
    ax.annotate('{}'.format(round(height, 1)),
                xy=(bar.get_x() + bar.get_width() / 2, height),
                xytext=(0, 10),  # 3 points vertical offset
                textcoords="offset points",
                ha='center', va='bottom',
                fontsize = 20).set_zorder(1)
    

ax2 = ax.twinx()
lineplot = sns.lineplot(x = years, y = values2, ax = ax2, color="gray")
```

the graph that the code produces:
[graph with line in fort of text annotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bi8Ds.png)

I tried changing the zorder on both axes and directly on the charts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately respecting zorder across twinned axes [is not possible](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/26734).  A workaround for annotations is to add them to the second axes, but using the data transform of the first.  See the *xycoords* parameter added in the call to annotate here:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

years = [2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2023]
values1 = [1350, 1360, 1420, 1480, 1650]
values2 = [57, 62, 60.5, 59.7, 62.3]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6.2, 7.36), dpi = 150)
bars = ax.bar(years, values1)

ax2 = ax.twinx()
lineplot = ax2.plot(years, values2, ls="-", color="gray")

for bar in bars:
    height = bar.get_height()
    ax2.annotate('{}'.format(round(height, 1)),
                 xy=(bar.get_x() + bar.get_width() / 2, height),
                 xytext=(0, 10),  # 3 points vertical offset
                 textcoords="offset points",
                 ha='center', va='bottom',
                 fontsize = 20,
                 xycoords=ax.transData)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Note that this can be simplified by using the `bar_label` method, which is a convenience wrapper for adding annotations to bars:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

years = [2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2023]
values1 = [1350, 1360, 1420, 1480, 1650]
values2 = [57, 62, 60.5, 59.7, 62.3]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6.2, 7.36), dpi = 150)
bars = ax.bar(years, values1)

ax2 = ax.twinx()
lineplot = ax2.plot(years, values2, ls="-", color="gray")
ax2.bar_label(bars, fontsize=20, padding=10, xycoords=ax.transData) 

plt.show()
```